# Microsoft Edge: Halt native smooth scroll with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Situation: user on edge is scrolling and clicks something. Since Edge has native smooth scrolling, the scroll animation is still running after their click. I have an animation that runs when they click, and the continuous window scrolling is messing with that animation.

Is there a way to programmatically end an in-progress native smooth scroll on Edge?

So far I've tried setting `window.scrollY = window.scrollY` with no luck.

Comment: Any way you can show us how to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Open edge. Scroll. Native scrolling is animated so after your mousewheel the scroll will continue to animate a little bit after your mousewheel input. I want to halt this animation and freeze the window scroll position if a particular element is clicked while the scroll animation is still running.

Comment: While trying to reproduce your steps I noticed that the scrolling animation immediately halts whenever I move the mouse. This is with Edge 107.0.1418.35 on OSX.

You could try listening for clicks on the `document` and set the `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` to the current scroll position.

Comment: If you want any particular element to be immediately located and displayed without any scrolling animation, `element.scrollIntoView()` seems to satisfy your need. You can have a try.